# Why is $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,P^*y\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, projection-matrices, self-adjoint-operators

This property is at the heart of a Wikipedia article on projections: [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projections).

I have not been able to make any headway in my understanding of the statement “A projection matrix $P$ is orthogonal if and only if it is Hermitian”. The article proves this by saying (I paraphrase): “well obviously $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,P^*y\rangle\implies P=P^*$”.

Any answers or hints would be greatly appreciated. As well as an explanation of the property $\langle Px,y\rangle=\langle x,P^*y\rangle$, if there are alternative explanations/intuitions for why an orthogonal projection must be Hermitian/self-adjoint I’d appreciate that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you quote is part of the proof of the direction "if a projection $P$ is orthogonal, then it is self-adjoint."

- If a projection $P$ is orthogonal, then $\langle x, Py \rangle = \langle Px, y\rangle$. (This is proved a few lines above by rearranging the orthogonality condition $\langle Px, y-Py\rangle = \langle x-Px, Py \rangle = 0$.)
- Next, the equation $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, P^* y\rangle$ holds by the definition of the adjoint. If it helps, think about matrix transposes and note that $(Px)^* y = x^* P^* y = x^* (P^* y)$.

Combining the two steps above yields $\langle x, Py \rangle = \langle Px, y\rangle = \langle x, P^* y\rangle$. **This holds for all $x$ and $y$.** In general if linear operators $A$ and $B$ satisfy $\langle x, A y \rangle = \langle x, B y\rangle$ **for all $x,y$**, then $A=B$. (One way to think about this is to consider $x,y$ being standard basis elements.) Thus $P=P^*$.

Comment: I take it $x*(P^*y)$ is the same as $\langle x,P^*y\rangle$ by definition of matrix multiplication? Thank you addressing the main point of my question

Comment: @IdioticShrike Yes, the typical Euclidean inner product (on $\mathbb{C}^n$) $\langle u, v\rangle$ is *defined* as $u^* v$.

Comment: I've been thinking about this question recently and I am aware of the reality of more abstract vector spaces and more abstract inner product spaces. Does your argument work in those situations too, where the inner product is not the trivial multiplication-and-sum?

Comment: @FShrike I believe so: everything in the problem (even the notion of an adjoint of a linear operator) can be expressed with respect to the abstract notion of an inner product.

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ is orthogonal then
$\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle Px, Py \rangle + \langle Px, y- Py \rangle = \langle Px, Py \rangle $. Switching $x,y$, we obtain $\langle x, Py \rangle =  \langle Px, Py \rangle $. Thus, $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle x, Py \rangle$ which implies $\langle Px, y \rangle = \langle P^*x, y \rangle$ and further implies $\forall x,y\,  \langle (P-P^*)x, y \rangle =0$. Taking $y =  (P-P^*)x$, we find $\| (P-P^*)x\| = 0$ for all $x$ which implies $P-P^* = 0$ and therefore $P = P^*$.

If $P^* = P$ then
$$\langle Px, y- Py \rangle  = \langle x, P^*y- P^*Py \rangle  = \langle x, Py- P^2y \rangle  = \langle x, Py- Py \rangle =0,$$
since $P^2 = P$.